# making span tag cover entire width of div

Tags: css, width, html

I have the following structure for html:-

```
<div>
  <span>
    <a href="wherever">Wherever</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

If I want the span to cover the entire width of the div, how can I do that in chrome?

I tried in css using

```
span{
  background:#FFF;
  width:100%;
}
```

It works in firefox and ie but not in chrome.

Comment: You could try to set `display:block;`. But i don't think the `span` element is really semantically correct for this job.

Comment: Why not remove the span and just style the div?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`span` elements are inline. Inline elements adjust their width automatically and ignore your `width:` expressions.

Make it block-level:

```
span {
    display: block;
}
```

But then it's basically just a `<div>`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to resolve your issue.

As span tags adjust their width according to the contents in it. So to assign width to this tag we will use float left with width.

```
span{
 background:#FFF;
 width:100%;
 float: left;
}
```

secod way is to use display block with the code

```
 span{
 background:#FFF;
 width:100%;
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: width:100% is very important. If I could I would give you tumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

Change span's CSS to:

```
span {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
div{
    padding:0px;
}
span{
    background:#FFF;
    width:100%;
}
```